# sh: xrealloc: .././subst.c:5265: cannot allocate 18446744071562067968 bytes

Tags: bash, memory

I have run the bash script `test.sh`.

In the line, `f=$(<data.txt)` I got the error below.

`test.sh: xrealloc: .././subst.c:5265: cannot allocate 18446744071562067968 bytes (4320051200 bytes allocated)`

But `data.txt` is only 3GB file.

Why was the error raised?

And how to avoid this kind of errors?

Comment: Have you considered not reading 3GB of data into a shell variable?

Comment: are you certain you have enough memory to allocate? Also, what @melpomene said :)

Comment: I have 256GB memory owing to workstation

Comment: btw, putting `sh:` in a title when your shell is bash rather than sh is a bit misleading.

Comment: ...that said, working with strings this large is really outside the realm of things bash is good at (regularly tested for, etc). Many of its built-in expansions &c. are known to be extremely inefficient when working with strings larger than a few K.

Answer (score 1):

Which bash version are you using? There are memory leaks which are fixed in 4.4 version. Check this out:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2015-06/msg00083.html